# BERT neglects dependency between the masked positions

Tags: nlp

Reading [XLNET](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.08237.pdf) paper, It was mentioned that:

> However, relying on corrupting the input with masks, BERT neglects
> dependency between the masked positions and suffers from a
> pretrain-finetune discrepancy.

we all know that transformers are using positional encoding to relate tokens in the sequences and referring to the BERT [code](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/514de24abfd4416aeba6a6455ad5920f57f3567d/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py#L1304)    BertModel   is using   BertEmbeddings   which used absolute positional encoding layer. My question is Why Bert after using positional encoding  neglects dependency between the masked positions? The explanation in the paper is not clear to me.

It was explained in the   Background subsection page-2 from the paper , but nothing mentioned about positional encoding between tokens in BERT.

If the positional encoding is not the only cosideration for tokens dependency so what are the other considerations?